# Checking for previous instance of application

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a code to check previous instance of the application in vb.net, my requirement is that application should prevent for same user and it should allow for different user who wants to access through remote parellel 2x client..Any one please help me on this...Thanks

Comment: Please explain what do you mean for "remote parallel 2x client".. remote desktop concurrent sessions? Different application instances with user authentication? Web application?

Comment: I think it means two different people signed into the same Server via RDP are allowed access...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VB.Net, You should definetly look into [WindowsFormsApplicationBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase) class, shipped as part of .NET framework.

There is a property ([IsSingleInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.issingleinstance)) specifically designed to provide single instance behavior to the application.
You can even receive notifications through [StartupNextInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance) or the counterpart `OnStartupNextInstance` method when another instance of the application tries to run.

I forgot to mention that `My.Application` already is an object of the `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` type (at least in VB.NET WinForms applications).

**UPDATE**:
Currently, to take advantage of this stuff from a VB.NET project you have to follow these steps:

1. Edit project properties.
2. Enable "Make single instance application".
3. Click "View Application Events".
4. (optionally) Implement `StartupNextInstance` event handler.

Comment: Actually per remote user mean different users on different sessions, unless otherwise specified. I just dropped a comment to get more information.

Comment: @CaiusJard This approach works for multiple users on different Terminal sessions; for each session, only one instance of the application is allowed, but each session can have its one instance.